# How to display dynamic Products on Website using AWS

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web, server, store

I'm new to the topic of webdesign and servers so maybe I just don't know the keywords to look for but here is my question:

I'd like to create an amazon.com like website. Basically a couple of filters and a huge amount of products. Then I want to use AWS to both store all my products and search for the best product matches for the given filters.

If anyone could direct me to a tutorial or guide or any reference at all I'd be very glad.

PS: I'm really new to all of this so I'd much appreciate a simple explanation!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on your technology choice, there are broadly two ways to host dynamic websites in AWS e.g. Shopping Cart, Marketplace, CRM, CMS solutions:

- Using servers i.e. EC2 instances
- Serverless using S3, Lambda, DynamoDB, RDS.

Both solutions have advantages and limitations and purely depends on your control over technology.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: I could use an EC2 instance, launch a database e.g. SQL on there containing the products, host the website on that server and put a piece of software on it to select products?

Comment: Absolutely every word in your comment is true. EC2 instance = Dedicated Server from any other hosting provider with full control over it's installation, configuration and security.

Comment: There are multiple ways how you can use EC2 instances in terms of pricing and configuration terms. If you want to know more about this, please let me know.

Comment: Okay I'm going to try to figure things out. If I should get stuck I'm going to resort back to your offer ;). Thank you very much!

Comment: Good Luck! Please let me know, if you need any help.